# Undefined reference to defined function using stdargs

Tags: c++, templates, g++

Good day everyone.

I need your skills with g++ to understand what's happening to me !

When trying to link, g++ tells me this:

```
undefined reference to `bool Script::Call<bool>(asIScriptFunction*, std::string, ...)'
```

Whereas that function is clearly defined in that file:

```
namespace Script
{
  template<typename RET>
  RET Call(asIScriptFunction* function, string fmt, ...)
  {
    asIScriptContext* context = Script::Engine::Get()->CreateContext();
    va_list ap;

    context->Prepare(function);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    for (unsigned short i = 0 ; fmt[i] ; ++i)
    {
      if (i == 'O')
    context->SetArgObject(i, va_arg(ap, void*));
      else if (i == 'b')
    context->SetArgByte(i, va_arg(ap, int));
      else if (i == 'i')
    context->SetArgDWord(i, va_arg(ap, int));
      else if (i == 'f')
    context->SetArgFloat(i, va_arg(ap, double));
    }
    va_end(ap);
    context->Execute();

    RET to_ret = ScriptCallGetReturn<RET>(context);
    context->Release();
    return (to_ret);
  }
}

namespace Script
{
  template<> bool  Call<bool> (asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);
  template<> int   Call<int>  (asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);
  template<> float Call<float>(asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);
  template<> void* Call<void*>(asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);

  template<>
  void Call<void>(asIScriptFunction* function, string fmt, ...)
  {
    asIScriptContext* context = Script::Engine::Get()->CreateContext();
    va_list ap;

    context->Prepare(function);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    for (unsigned short i = 0 ; fmt[i] ; ++i)
    {
      switch (fmt[i])
      {
    case '0':
      context->SetArgObject(i, va_arg(ap, void*));
      break ;
    case 'b':
      context->SetArgByte(i, va_arg(ap, int));
      break ;
    case 'i':
      context->SetArgDWord(i, va_arg(ap, int));
      break ;
    case 'f':
      context->SetArgFloat(i, va_arg(ap, double));
      break ;
      }
    }
    va_end(ap);
    context->Execute();
    context->Release();
  }
}
```

And indeed, these templates should be compiled (they're literally in the same file that uses them).
What could be the reason for this to happen ? Could it be because of my use of stdarg ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> template<> bool  Call (asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);

This is not doing what you think it is doing. This is declaring a full template specialization of `template <typename RET> Call` with `RET` <- `bool`. You haven't defined it, and that old definition is out the door. Function template specialization is a weird beast, something probably best avoided.

What you are trying to do, I think, is to tell the compiler that you will be using an instantiation of `Call`. You don't need to do that. Just use it.

```
bool variable_name = Call<bool> (some_script, other_args);
```

Answer (score 4):

The function is declared but it is not implemented there. The linker is looking for the implementation. Notice that only `Call<void>` is implemented in the code you supplied but `Call<bool>` is'nt.

All you have to do for you'er code to be linked properly is remove the declarations:

```
  template<> bool  Call<bool> (asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);
  template<> int   Call<int>  (asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);
  template<> float Call<float>(asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);
  template<> void* Call<void*>(asIScriptFunction*, string fml, ...);
```

Comment: Holy cow. I forgot half the code -_-... that specialization isn't even relevant here...

Comment: @user626921 `Call<bool>` (as well as `Call<int>` and `Call<float>`) is still (after your unmarked edit) not defined (implemented), but only declared...

Comment: Doesn't it mean that I can't use template for this ? If I have to implement it, then I have to do so for every type, don't I ? And doing so I end up doing the same amount of work than without template.

Comment: So yeah. It does mean I can't use templates... it works if I implement them, but then I have to copy-paste the code 4 times. It's disappointing and I hate it but I'm gonna have to use a macro. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user626921 - You do not have to cut-and-paste the code four times. That's one of the key points of templates.

Comment: @user1708860 - `Call<bool>` *would* have been defined if that extraneous declaration wasn't present. There's no need for; it does more harm than good.

Comment: @David Hammen
oops, i meant declared, not defined. and i never said it does any good...